# Using std::move(object) and object.method() in the same assignment expression.

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Is the result of the following expression well-defined? What is it?

`hash_map[object.key()] = std::move(object);`

I'm not sure whether the effects of `std::move` part would occur before or after the `object.key()` part, hence my question.

Comment: I suppose it is going to have difficulty executing the *move* before *dereferencing* the element that is going to be moved into....

Comment: Not a C++ expert, but I'm pretty sure `move` doesn't *have* any effects. It just creates an rvalue reference. It's the assignment that actually moves data out of `object`, and the assignment is sequenced after `object.key()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is well defined because it doesn't matter what comes first in this code: You can rewrite it to the following equivalent

```
hash_map[object.key()] = static_cast<objecttype&&>(object);
```

What can we say about the code:

1. `object.key()` should be executed before assignment to the map
2. `std::move(object)` should be executed before assignment to the map

Then there will be the assignment to the map which will accept xvalued `object` with whatever changes `key` function did.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize invoking std::move doesn't actually move anything.

Comment: @nicebyte, I'd recommend to read Item 23 from the latest Scott Meyers book if you can get your hands on it. It has a pretty good explanation of the `std::move` and `std::forward` functions